# Disable sound output device in 12.04?

Tags: soundcard, indicator-sound

I need to be able to disable a sound device in 12.04.

I was able to do this in 11.10 using the Sounds Setting app, and it worked like a charm.  The new Sound Settings app doesn't seem to have the capability of outright disabling an output device.

I'm trying to disable a AMD HDMI sound device associated with my Radeon HD 6870 Video card.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Does muting it not fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but no. I need to completely disable the output device.

I've got a script (pinned to the launcher) that I used in 11.10 to switch between output devices (speakers and headset) with one click rather than going through several clicks via the indicator app to accomplish the same thing.

The script seems to not be able to skip through the HDMI device of my HD 6870 without disabling the device completely.

Sad, it worked so well in 11.10 to be able to disable the device from the sound settings applet.  It's frustrating when a new release (especially an LTS) loses functionality rather than gains it.

One step forward, two steps back I guess.

Comment: OK, I was able to disable the devices by installing pavucontrol and doing it there.