# Disable HDMI sound out, for decrease power consumption

Tags: power-management, hdmi, soundcard

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop
I'm looking for a way to decrease power consumption.
This is output of `powertop` command

```
Power est.      Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
1.30 W          100.0%                  Device         Audio codec hwC0D0: Realtek
```

I googled a little and find this 100.0% usage related to digital output through HDMI port.
I'm looking for a way to disable digital output or HDMI pot, I don't use this port anyway.
Also I want to have sound.
I put some sound module in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
blacklist snd_hda_codec_realtek
blacklist snd_hda_intel
blacklist snd_hda_codec
```

Problem solved, but there is not any sound.
Any idea appreciated in advance.

Edited : More illustration about the problem

output of 'aplay -l' is

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC269VB Digital [ALC269VB Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I've wanted to turn off Digital device, because i thinked it is source of power consumption, according to `powertop`'s output.

Here, what I did.
Added following line at the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
blacklist snd_hda_codec_realtek
```

After restart, Output of `aplay -l` is:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: HDA Generic [HDA Generic]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and output of `lsmod | grep snd` is

```
snd_hda_intel          32765  3 
snd_hda_codec         109562  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80916  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51592  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    62218  13     snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              14635  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
```

Unfortunately output of `powertop` shows no change

```
powertop : in Device stats
Power est.    Usage     Device name
1.26 W        100.0%    Audio codec hwC0D0: Realtek
```

Also in this situation i have not any sound!

Again, I'm looking forward to see your opinion, idea.

Comment: forget blacklisting... http://askubuntu.com/questions/113364/disable-sound-output-device-in-12-04 -> Install pavucontrol

Comment: @Rinzwind: I installed pavucontrol, and tried to change some configs, but always `powertop` output about _Audio codec_ does not change at all! :(

Comment: @soroosh "I googled a little and find this 100.0% usage related to digital output through HDMI port". Can you provide the link?

Comment: yes of course, this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91359/100-0-usage-by-audio-codec-hwc0d0-realtek) is what i said.