# Ubuntu switches Sound Device when Headphones are plugged in

Tags: sound

I have two devices for sound output:

[image]

Always when I plug in my headphones or external speakers - for whatever reason - the Digital Output gets selected which means in this case that I have no sound at all.

How can I keep the from system switching the device?

Comment: Okay I just had luck by adding `blacklist snd_hda_codec_realtek`, `blacklist snd_hda_intel` and `blacklist snd_hda_codec` to the blacklist `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270312/disable-hdmi-sound-out-for-decrease-power-consumption

Comment: You can also install `sound-switcher-indicator` to quickly switch audio output/ Instructions: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/sound-switcher-app-ubuntu